# The regular expression to validate a string that ensures words should be separated by only one special symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"/(?=.{1,32}$)^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-.:]*)[a-zA-Z0-9]$/"
```

I have the above regular expression, it accepts only a few special characters and ensures that the string should not start or end with special symbols

### Current Accepted strings :

1. abcd
2. abcd-gffgfg
3. abcdeer-errt.ertert-rtr
4. abcd-._:fgdfgfg ( Which should not be allowed )

### Current Rejected strings :

1. abcd-
2. abcd$fgfg
3. -&abcd
4. -abcd

I want to modify the above expression to accept only one special character between any two words and allow only a few special symbols ( . _ - : )

Suggest me how to modify the above regular expression.

Comment: The 1st *invalid string* is same to 3rd *accepted string*

Comment: Edited post check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
const regex = /(?=.{1,32}$)^(([a-zA-Z0-9])+[_\-.:])*([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/
const strs = [
  "abcd-abcd",
  "abcd_fdfg-dfgdg.fgd:dfgdfg",
  "abcd",
  "abcd-._:abcd",
  "abcd:dfgdfg:_:"
]

console.log(strs.map(str => regex.test(str)))
```

The regex basically says: (wordchars + 1 special char) repeated 0 or more times followed by wordchars.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` can be simplified to `[^\W_]` and you can remove some useless capture groups that slow down the process. `/^(?=.{1,32}$)(?:[^\W_]+[-_.:])*[^\W_]+$/`